# Can PHP Unlink() delete multiple files based on a pattern?

Tags: php, unlink

I want to know if unlink() function can delete multiple files based on a pattern for example:

```
unlink('./directory/(*).txt');
```

Is there something like that to delete multiple files (.txt files for example) without the need of glob() and loops?

Comment: You can't do that. `ulink` can delete just one.

Comment: What's wrong with `glob() and loops` ?  The core PHP functionally cant do everything for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but  this is only 77 bytes or 69 with single letter variables:

```
array_map('unlink',preg_filter('/^/',$dir,preg_grep($regex,scandir($dir))));
//array_map('unlink',preg_filter('/^/',$d,preg_grep($r,scandir($d))));
```

Untested, should work in theory (Maybe).  `$dir` is the directory with an ending slash.  `$regex` is a full Regular expression.

> without the need of glob() and loops

No glob, no loop.  Although I did use `array_map` but I did it without a closure.

For testing:

```
$dir = 'somefolder/';

//scandir($dir)
$files = ['index.php', 'image.jpg', 'somefile.php'];

//look for files ending in .php
$regex = '/\.php$/';

//strval is useless here but, it shows it works, these are strings so it just returns what we already have
$files = array_map('strval', preg_filter('/^/', $dir, preg_grep($regex, $files)));

//I could have used 'print_r' instead of 'strval' but this is formatted better!
print_r($files);
```

Output

```
//these would be sent to unlink
Array
(
    [0] => somefolder/index.php
    [2] => somefolder/somefile.php
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/84285f4b46647e9c6f952a63cb8f516013b19018)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) says that you can only pass a single file, just like C's `unlink`.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the show, but there's a very simple solution to this.

You can use the array_map() and glob() to match a pattern:

```
// Delete all ".txt" files in folder "files"
array_map('unlink', glob("files/*.txt"));
```

Hope this helps someone else.